# React: understanding refs and targeting child refs

Tags: reactjs, ref

I have a react app organized like so:

```
class AppLayout extends Component { 

  componentDidMount () {
    this.data = this.getEndpoint('some endpoint')
  }
  ...

  render () { 

    return (
    <Header data={this.data} />
    <PageContent data={this.data} />
    <Footer data={this.data} />
     )
    }
}
```

inside header, different child components are rendered till eventually a menu and some Link components and/or 'a' tags are rendered based on a menu of data received from the API.

meanwhile, PageContent goes through a subcomponent of the API data 
and renders some other child components based on that.

PageContent is organized like

```
<PageSection >
   <Child>
   <Child>
</PageSection>

<PageSection>
   <Child>
   <Child>
</PageSection>
```

the menu has some same page anchor links, that refer to these 'dynamically' created PageSections, refs to each page section are declared in each PageSection component

I'm struggling to find a way to be able somehow reference these refs in the menu child Link components
i.e. make a '#' link scroll to the correct position

```
        PARENT
          |
    ------------------
    |                 | 
PAGECONTENT        MENUS
    |                 |
PAGESECTION       CHILD LINK
```

basically, CHILD LINK has an anchor '#some-id', and PAGESECTION has a defined ref of [some-id]

What's the proper pattern (or any pattern!) for enabling something like

```
const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode([hash anchor])
if (node) {
  node.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center'})
```

within a Link component?

currently not using flux/redux

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<Link to="/header#child">Go</Link>
```

You may also look at [this thread](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/394) to work with scroll into view. There are good solutions.

Comment: thanks for the response. this causes a page refresh and browserRouter  registers a route change, react rerenders the page, currently i'm looking to control same page scrolling edit: thanks for the link i'll read through that.

Comment: Go through the provided links, you may find a solution.